# Markers not created after passing JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3

Edit after help from Roberto:

Python newbie. The app uses Maps Javascript API v3 on the front end. Backend is webapp2/GAE. I'm assuming I'm not doing the json properly either. Markers not created properly after passing the JSON.

```
    q = Building.query()
    buildings = q.fetch()
    some_json = []
    for building in buildings:
        some_json.append(OrderedDict([('lat', float(building.lat)), ('lng', float(building.lng)), ('content', building.uuid)]))
    appended_json = json.dumps(some_json)
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDMfzvCXM-LUe43cZ0mB2iDxx4aNOySkrQ">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
            var input_value = document.getElementById("lat").value;
            var converted_value = JSON.stringify(input_value);
            console.log(input_value);
            var json = JSON.parse(converted_value);
            console.log(json);
            var locations = json;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][2]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
    }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <input id="lat" hidden="hidden" value="{{ appended_json }}">

  </body>
</html>
```

Console outputs the following, if the output is proper and raises no errors:

```
 [{"lat": 39.2831792, "lng": -80.56741099999999, "content": "782f7100c13511e49f92ab5e18d4b38e"}] viewbuildings:17 
[{"lat": 39.2831792, "lng": -80.56741099999999, "content": "782f7100c13511e49f92ab5e18d4b38e"}]
```

Even if the output is not proper, it still not raises anything.

Edit:

Exact HTML browser sees is the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDMfzvCXM-LUe43cZ0mB2iDxx4aNOySkrQ">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
            var input_value = document.getElementById("lat").value;
            var converted_value = JSON.stringify(input_value);
            console.log(input_value);
            var json = JSON.parse(converted_value);
            console.log(json);
            var locations = json;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][2]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
    }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <input id="lat" hidden="hidden" value="[{&quot;lat&quot;: 39.2831792, &quot;lng&quot;: -80.56741099999999, &quot;content&quot;: &quot;782f7100c13511e49f92ab5e18d4b38e&quot;}]">

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ...no replies yet, so you'll have to do with me. What do you mean that the append is inconsistent? Standard dictionaries in Python aren't ordered. The two outputs you show after "However the output tends to be different everytime" are equivalent to me, unless I'm overlooking something.

Comment: @Roberto I'll take that :) My bad, you are right, they are equivalent, however the ordering is different almost every time I run the query.. What would be the proper way to implement the ordering - lat, lng, content?

Comment: Um, perhaps one option is to `from collections import OrderedDict` and then `some_json.append(OrderedDict([('lat', float(building.lat)), ('lng', float(building.lng)), ('content', building.uuid)]))`

Comment: That has solved the "consistency", or better to say ordered the dictionary properly. Thank you! :)

Comment: What is the issue? What does the HTML the browser sees look like?  What does the JSON look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Markers are not being created, I tried and stated that in the topic of the question. I've updated the question to provide the HTML the browser sees. The JSON I have already provided in the logs. @geocodezip

Comment: The title says they aren't being created "properly".  I don't know what that means.

Comment: You only have one marker and it is out of the viewport?

Comment: My apologies. I have edited the topic question. For now, yes. I want to use that template to create markers from the json I pass it to. I construct json from the webapp2 query which is different for every user. @geocodezip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is expecting your JSON to look like this:

```
[[39.2831792,-80.56741099999999,"782f7100c13511e49f92ab5e18d4b38e"]]
```

Your JSON doesn't look like that, it looks like:

```
[{"lat": 39.2831792,"lng": -80.56741099999999,"content": "782f7100c13511e49f92ab5e18d4b38e"}];
```

Change the code to process your JSON format:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lng),
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i].content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

You are also using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` incorrectly.  The content of your input element is a JSON string, you only need to pass it to `JSON.parse` to get a JSON object out of it:

working code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  var input_value = document.getElementById("lat").value;
  var json = JSON.parse(input_value);
  var locations = json;

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lng),
      map: map
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i].content);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<input id="lat" hidden="hidden" value="[{&quot;lat&quot;: 39.2831792, &quot;lng&quot;: -80.56741099999999, &quot;content&quot;: &quot;782f7100c13511e49f92ab5e18d4b38e&quot;}]">
```

Comment: I have tried the solution you have proposed but without luck fixing the issue. I tried logging the pass through the loop, it passed 95 times, so then I changed the `var locations = [json]` and then it passed only once. However the marker is still not shown :( I tried manually centering the map to the exact coordinates passed. Also, if I pass more info in json, it still says one, so I assume I have to slice it and fix it.

Comment: Thank you, this has worked. I have one question prior to marking this answer as correct. How would I make the setContent create a link with lets say `href="/viewbuilding" + locations[i].content` ?

Comment: That is another question.